# HQL bulk insert into a junction table?

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hql, bulkinsert

I am in a situation where I need to quickly associate ten of thousands of an object with another single object and iterating over them to associate the object one by one seems extremely wasteful.

Is it possible in Hibernate HQL to do a bulk insert into a junction table (aka cross reference table)? And if so, what does that look like?

Comment: You will be better off constructing a straight sql insert statement and doing batch insertions.